# Convert bidimensional table to a single one

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have some data with product prices relative to tariff code :

```
+==============+========+========+========+========+
| product code | code10 | code20 | code30 | code40 |
|==============+========+========+========+========|
| product1     | 12.3   | 12.4   | 12.5   | 12.6   |
+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| product2     | 13.3   | 13.4   | 13.5   | 13.6   |
+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| product3     | 14.3   | 14.4   | 14.5   | 14.6   |
+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to get a table with three columns : product code, price and tariff code

```
+==============+=======+=============+
| product code | price | tariff code |
|==============+=======+=============+
| product1     | 12.3  | code10      |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
| product1     | 12.4  | code20      |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
| product1     | 12.5  | code30      |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
| product1     | 12.6  | code40      |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
| product2     | 13.3  | code10      |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
| product2     | 13.4  | code20      |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
| ........     | ....  | ......      |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
| product3     | 14.6  | code40      |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
```

I tried to acheive this with a custom paste without success.
Is there anyway to do this with Calc ?

Comment: Can you use pivot tables?

Comment: @DaveRook: Since Pivot tables aren't trivial to use, it would be worth an answer how to solve this using pivot tables.

Comment: I'm open to any solution, but if there's no quite simple way to do this in Calc, I would make a small script to end up with this result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments of the OP, you mention using a script. This VBa does it, saving the results to another sheet.

Even if your machine doesn't support VBa, the script may give you an idea so you can port it over in your preferred language.

Remember, with VBa, undo usually doesn't work, so save a copy of the file first as a back up!!

```
Sub DoSomeMagic()

Call CreateHeadings

Dim row As Integer
row = 2

Dim sheet2row As Integer
sheet2row = 2

Do While (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value <> "")


Dim col As Integer
col = 66

    Do While (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Chr(col) & row).Value <> "")

        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & sheet2row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & sheet2row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Chr(col) & row).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & sheet2row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Chr(col) & 1).Value
           col = col + 1
           sheet2row = sheet2row + 1
    Loop

    row = row + 1

Loop

End Sub

Sub CreateHeadings()

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = "product code"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value = "price"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Font.Bold = True
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Value = "tariff code"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

Original (Sheet1)

[image]

After running VBa, sheet2 looks like

[image]